# Spark streamming take long time read from kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I build a cluster use CDH5.14.2, includes 5 nodes, each node has 130G momery and 40 cpu cores. I builded the spark streamming application to read from multiple kafka topic, about 10 kafka topics, and aggregate the kafka message separately. And save the kafka offset into zookeeper finally. Finally i found spark task take long time to process kafka message. The kafka message is not skew, and i found spark take long to read from kafka.

```
My code script:

// build input steeam from kafka topic
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream1 = MyKafkaUtils.
    buildInputStream(KafkaConfig.kafkaFlowGrouppId, topic1, ssc);
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream2 = MyKafkaUtils.
    buildInputStream(KafkaConfig.kafkaFlowGrouppId, topic2, ssc);
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream3 = MyKafkaUtils.
    buildInputStream(KafkaConfig.kafkaFlowGrouppId, topic3, ssc);
...

// aggregate kafka message use spark sql
result1 = process(stream1);
result2 = process(stream2);
result3 = process(stream3);
...

// write result to kafka kafka
writeToKafka(result1);
writeToKafka(result2);
writeToKafka(result3);

// save offset to zookeeper
saveOffset(stream1);
saveOffset(stream2);
saveOffset(stream3);
```

spark web ui information:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa6Jr.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concern. Is the issue here that the processing of each batch (which includes reading messages) is taking longer than you expect (so that includes even the ones that have completed where the average processing time is 1 - 2 minutes) or is the problem that the particular batch you're currently processing was stuck? It's also not impossible to say that this is just a Kafka issue. There's a lot you're doing in each batch (SQL, write data to Kafka, and save data in Zookeeper). Committing offsets to Zookeeper might not be the best choice either for performance.

Comment: Assuming that the concern is that the tasks in that particular executor is not progressing, have you tried collecting a Java thread dump of that executor to see what the worker tasks are doing? Have you also confirmed the health of your Kafka topics in Kafka? I see you have 20 tasks, so I'm guessing you have 20 Kafka topic partitions in total, is that right? How many cores and executors are you using for this Spark application?

Comment: Finally i found the method of reading from multiple kafka topic cause to the abnormal process time. I try build DStream from all kafka topics, and filter the message,  finally i found process time graph is smooth and smaller  than before.